# Error logging in the admin panel Fatal error: Class 'Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data' not found .../app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.7

When I log into the admin panel I get this error at the top, Fatal error: Class 'Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data' not found  .../app/Mage.php on line 546

and i can see any menu?

Mage.php

```
 public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }
```

Comment: The error is that the file "Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data" is missing, did you install an extension recently?

Answer (score 6):

It's very possible that your shop was hacked last night!

Check for new files from last night in your extensions folders, install Secuirty Patch SUPEE-5344 and rename your admin folder.

Affacted systems shows new users with admin permissions.

=> https://rackspeed.de/blog/bruteforce-attacken-und-hacks-von-magento-shops/

@Dashpuppy Jason:

- Remove all files: app/code/community/Magpleasure/Filesystem/
- Clear your cache, login should be possible now.
- Check for new "Admin Users"
- Patch your System with SUPEE-5344!

Comment: Do you have any actual proof for this FUD?

Comment: Yes, many customer complaints about broken / hacked magento systems. We have a list with similarities of affected shops in our blog: New extension was installed last night, SUPEE-5344 is missing, BruteForce on /admin/ folder and new files in the downloader cache with the same timestamp. ;)

Comment: Really? Customers never learn. Who still keeps their downloader folder world wide open and a default admin path. I read the blog, looks solid. I remember this vendor from a while back though. I'll have to search our ticket system, maybe the name is slightly different.

Comment: Heise Security has also an Alert online: http://www.heise.de/security/meldung/Luecke-in-eBays-Shopsystem-Magento-Beliebiger-Schadcode-ausfuehrbar-2617112.html I think it is related to: http://blog.checkpoint.com/2015/04/20/analyzing-magento-vulnerability/

Comment: Clearing the cache folder didn't quite work for me. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65097/fatal-error-class-magpleasure-filesystem-helper-data-not-found/65119#65119?newreg=7687cba75bc14bc6a590ee7421f456fb for a better solution using a CLI tool

Comment: I'm working with a few others to document each attack signature discovered.  Does the blog post include everything you've come across or just the highlights? I'd love to get everyone who has anything to share involved in the open source project we started to share our work with the community.

Per Wim's comment, we used n98-magerun and it was so helpful that we're releasing our research and a set of add-ons to extend it to identify & fix the signatures we document.  Please consider sharing whatever you can at https://github.com/comitdevelopers/magento-security-toolkit

Comment: We just started the project and are working to wrap up coding and testing asap, but we're dumping our findings and everything that was submitted to us from others at https://github.com/comitdevelopers/magento-security-toolkit/blob/master/signatures-analysis.md

Please fork, update, & submit a pull request for anything you can add.  You all seem like you're as busy as we have been assisting clients fighting these attacks and I'm sure there's plenty wisdom you could share to make the project even more helpful to others like us as well as our clients - everything you offer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you call helper of a module you have not enabled.

Check Magpleasure_Filesystem mobule please.