# Fatal error: Class 'Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento-1.9

I have this error also accross the banner in my admin page and cannot access admin section.  I was told by 1&1 my site was hacked about 2 weeks ago, I have not added any modules or touched site in some time so I didn't cause issue.

I would like to know how to get rid of this problem though?  Someone mentioned there was a patch to install. If I cannot access back end, how do I edit anything?
I can edit mage.php file, but I am not a programmer so can someone please advise what I need to do?

Steven

Comment: I would first check that the class `Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data` exists. Does it?

Answer (score 2):

Recovering from this exploit:

1. If you are running on a cheap "magento optimized" host that does not provide ssh access or a very limited shell, you are about to find out how expensive cheap really is. Recovering from this with only FTP or limited shell access may require restoring a file back up and associated downtime.
2. Edit the file `app/etc/modules/Magpleasure_Filesystem.xml` and change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`. Do not try to make the module working, as it is an exploit module that has been removed from Magento Connect since that was discovered to be the case.
3. Now you need to refresh the configuration cache. Since this can't be done from your admin panel, you will need to use a shell tool. Preferably use [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/) and issue the command `n98-magerun.phar cache:flush` to thoroughly purge the cache and make Magento build a new module list which now no longer includes the bogus module. If you cannot issue commands on the server and are using file cache, you should delete all directories below `var/cache/`. If you can't do that either (for whatever reason), restore a backup from before the hack and hope it contains the `var/cache` directories (remember point 1 while you're waiting for your restore to complete). If you are using a different cache backend, like Redis or memcache, look for a way to purge the Magento caches in the hoster provided control panel. If you don't have that either, really really really consider moving hosting companies!
4. If point 3 succeeded, you should now be able to access your backend.

Point 5 should really be "now do a thorough review of your code and database or hire someone to do that for you", but to prevent this from happening in the meantime, install the security patch called "SUPEE-5344". Since Magento isn't particularly patch-friendly by providing patches only to logged in users, various parties have mirrored this critical patch. See for instance [this wiki](https://www.byte.nl/wiki/How_to_apply_Magento_patch_SUPEE-5344) entry for mirrors and additional information.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. http://magento.com/security-patch works great to test that the admin is safe as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the Helper by yourself. Go to app/code/[local][community]/Magpleasure/Filesystem/Helper and create a file there called Data.php with this content:

```
<?php

class Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

and then in your module ./app/code/community/[local][community]/Magpleasure/Filesystem/etc/config.xml, within the  tags

```
<helpers>
  <mymodule>
      <class>MyName_MyModule_Helper</class>
  </mymodule>
</helpers>
```

Source [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/magento-1-7-creating-a-custom-helper-class-module).

Comment: This isn't an actual module. It's part of an exploit in circulation for the issues [mentioned here](http://blog.checkpoint.com/2015/04/20/analyzing-magento-vulnerability/).

Comment: Actually this is a module. The fact that is being used for an exploit does not invalidate my answer. The only way a regular user can access again to the admin is creating the class I added. After that anyone should check for extra users or strange behaviour, but until then the solution for the blank screen remains.

Comment: Details: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64461/error-logging-in-the-admin-panel-fatal-error-class-magpleasure-filesystem-help/64467?s=2|0.1298#64467 and OP already mentioned he's hacked. The goal of the question is how to prevent the hack, not how to fix the module.